# Gathering EBS metric using Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, monitoring

I am new to AWS.We have a use case where we periodically need to monitor EBS volumes for disk usage and post custom metric to cloudwatch.

To get the amount of disk usage on ec2 box we can run df -h command.In my lambda I am given a tag and then from that tag I have monitor EBS of EC2 instances having that tag.

I was doing research and I found this article [runn shell commands on EC2](https://medium.com/@Electricste/run-shell-commands-on-a-ec2-from-a-lambda-function-108994911064).But how do I list EC2 instances having a particular tag and then run 
this df -h command on them.Also is there a better way to monitor disk usage?

Edit : I was able to run cloudwatch script as

```
./mon-put-instance-data.pl --disk-space-util --disk-path=/ebs1 --disk-path=/ --disk-space-units=Kilobytes
```

and get the disk usage for above volumes mounted on /ebs1 and /

I am now planning to use a python script to get all the mounted EBS programatically to replace values of --disk-path.

How to do it in EC2 via Python?

Comment: What programming language are you writing the AWS Lambda function in? You would use the AWS SDK for whatever programming language you pick to query for EC2 instance with a specific tag.

Comment: I am using Java.Is running shell command on each EC2 instance a good way to do this?

Comment: Doing this via Lambda is not ideal. Ideally you would have some sort of agent running on each server always reporting things like memory and disk usage to CloudWatch.

Comment: @MarkB progress updated

Comment: Why do you need to integrate python with the `mon-put-instance-data.pl` script? What are you trying to solve exactly that `mon-put-instance-data.pl` doesn't already provide?

Comment: @MarkB I need to figure out the mounted paths of EBS volumes to replace in mon-put-instance-data.pl.So basically we are trying to periodically monitor EBS volumes for disk usage for a group of EC2 instances via given tag.I can schedule mon-put-instance-data script directly or via Lambda where each mon-put-instance-data command is triggered on separate EC2 instances having a specific tag.I am just thinking to have a python script(trigged by Lambda) deployed on each EC2 instance that figures out the mount paths of each EBS volume on a given EC2 and then trigger mon-put-instance-data.pl script.

Comment: You really don't need Lambda for this, just schedule cron jobs on each server.

Comment: @MarkB Yes,but still need a way to manually figure out mount paths of EBS volumes attached to EC2 instance and I feel that scheduling by Lambda might be better in case we add new instance with a given tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe using [a cloud watch agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AgentReference.html) is much better option.

As well you could define your own metrics (such as available disk space)

Comment: But won't that requires installing agent on every instance?

Comment: @ayushrocker92 indeed.. on the other side, you can create your own image with the agent already pre-installed.

Comment: But suppose i have 50 instances already running with the same tag then?

Comment: @ayushrocker92  I'd recommend using an automation tool, such as Ansible, it can configure 50 servers at once. I mean - you can still invoke the [DescribeInstance](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeInstances.html) operation (either CLI or  API) and parse the tags, however I believe having an agent is much more robust way to achieve the goal.

Comment: The CloudWatch Agent you linked is for posting logs to CloudWatch Logs, not metrics. The question is about posting metrics.

Comment: @MarkB you are right, I stay corrected, but he could google for better resource too https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html  but the basic idea stays :)